# Unable to deploy my servlet from a Maven Project on Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have an existing maven project on eclipse, into which I have included a servlet class (`ConfigFileInput.java`):

[image: Project classes]

`ConfigFileInput.java` is the servlet class, whereas the other classes are normal java classes, and `CreateMasterConfig.java` contains the main method.

I want to deploy this servlet on a local Tomcat server. I have the necessary maven dependencies and configurations setup properly, and maven generates a `.war` file successfully.

When I upload this `.war` file onto my Tomcat server and deploy it, it fails to start. 
So, I looked up the directory for my webapp in the Tomcat folder, and found that all the relevant classes are present.

I suspect that my servlet fails to deploy because the main method is in `CreateMasterConfig.java` whereas the servlet class is `ConfigFileInput.java`, but I'm not sure if this is true, and how I should correct this.

I would appreciate some advice on this.

**EDIT**

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">

<display-name>ConfigFileInput</display-name>
<description>
   This application accepts a URL from user to read the Config File, validates it,
   and merges into MasterConfigFile
</description>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ConfigFileInput</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ConfigFileInput</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConfigFileInput</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ConfigFileInput</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**EDIT 2:**

Just checked out the log files generated by Tomcat, and came across this error:

```
SEVERE: End event threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
at org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.callMethod1(IntrospectionUtils.java:802)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetNextRule.end(SetNextRule.java:201)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1057)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1742)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2900)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1543)
```

Comment: Can you share your web.xml

Comment: @JunedAhsan, added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is change the servlet name with complete package name as mentioned by msangel in his/her answer.

Secondly you need to understand the error message:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml addServlet
```

This generally happens when you are trying to deploy catalina.jar within your .war file. Just fix the build file to NOT to include the catalina.jar file in the .war file. This should take off this error.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`<servlet-class>ConfigFileInput</servlet-class>`

to:

`<servlet-class>edu.apollogrp.dfe.configuration.masterconfig.ConfigFileInput</servlet-class>`

This should fix your error.
And you should know some words about [servlet life-cycle](https://www.google.com/search?q=servlet%20life-cycle). There is no reqires of any `main method` in servlets.